# Why cannot export function inside default object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, export, create-react-app

I'm wondering why this is not valid on an application created using `create-react-app`:

```
/***** myLib.js *****/
const multiplyByTwo = val => val * 2;

export default { multiplyByTwo };
```

Nor:

```
/***** myLib.js *****/
let multiplyByTwo = val => val * 2;

export default { multiplyByTwo };
```

Neither:

```
/***** myLib.js *****/
function multiplyByTwo(val) { return val * 2; };

export default { multiplyByTwo };
```

Then, in another file:

```
/***** main.js *****/
import { multiplyByTwo } from './myLib'

console.log(multiplyByTwo(10));
```

When I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/main.js
Attempted import error: 'multiplyByTwo' is not exported from './myLib'
```

However, this is valid:

```
/***** myLib.js *****/
export const multiplyByTwo = val => val * 2;
```

Also this:

```
/***** myLib.js *****/
export let multiplyByTwo = val => val * 2;
```

Comment: in case of ```let multiplyByTwo = val => val * 2; export default { multiplyByTwo };``` you should import it like ```import helper from './myLib'``` and use it like ```helper.multiplyByTwo(3)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is between *named exports* and the *default export*.

When you use `export default <expression>`, that expression becomes available for importing elsewhere when you use `import exprName from ...`. The module is exporting `expression` as the default export, and `import exprName` takes the default export of that module and puts it into `exprName`. But the syntax `import { exprName }` is something [entirely different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import); that syntax indicates that you want to extract the *named export* of name `exprName` from the module. It's not destructuring, even though it looks a lot like it.

Your `myLib.js` does not have a named export of `multiplyByTwo` (it only has a *default export* of an object, which has a *property* named `multiplyByTwo`), so

```
import { multiplyByTwo } from './myLib'
```

fails.

It would make the most sense to use a named export instead from `myLib`:

```
export const multiplyByTwo = val => val * 2;
```

and then it can be imported with the `import { multiplyByTwo }` syntax you're using elsewhere.

Another option, using the same code in your original `myLib`, would be to import the default exported object, and then destructure it *after* importing:

```
import myLib from './myLib';
const { multiplyByTwo } = myLib;
```

But that looks a bit odd.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about the difference between a default export and a named export:

Let say you have an App.js and if you do something like

```
export default () => {
  // do something
}
```

That's a default export and 'limited' to a single import like so

```
import App from './App'
```

A named export would be something like:

```
export const add = (a, b) => a + b;
```

That's a named export and yo import it with the curly braces like so:

```
import { app } from './app'
```

More info [here](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910)

Answer (score 0):

Using **default** while exporting is when you would like to **export** something by default, which means when some other file is importing this they don't need to specify a particular name to import, this is called **Default Export**.

**Example:**

```
import React from 'react';
```

In this case, we don't specify a particular intended name when importing, here **React** can also be **reactDefaultExport** this name is a user-defined name.

Coming to **Named Exports**, when you want to export something specific, which needs to be imported with the exact name, then we use names exports.

**Example:**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
```

In this **Component** is a named export, when we use a **functional/ stateless** components we don't need Component, so we can avoid importing it, but React is a Default export.